# Prove if $S \subseteq Ass_N(M)$ then their exist a submodule $N$ such that $Ass_R(N)=S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is a $R$-module.

I am trying to prove,

If $S \subseteq Ass_R(M)$ then their exist a submodule $N$ such that $Ass_R(N)=S$.

I want use Zorn lemma to prove this problem. Let $N'$ be an element of  a collection of submodules such that $Ass_R(N') \subseteq S$. This collection of submoules is partially ordered. Must exist a maximal element by Zorn's lemma...

Comment: How are you partially ordering the submodules? This is important if you’re trying to do it this way because you want $Ass_R$ to be larger i.e. equal to $S’$. Recall that an associated prime of a module is a prime that is the annihilator of some element in that module.

Comment: Ordering the submodules by subsets. Then I will let Maximal elements $N_K$ will be the $N_1 \subseteq N_2 \subseteq ... \subseteq N_K$ of the chain of submodules. 
Issue now is there could be multiple maximal element. I want to  prove there is only one maximal it contains all of the $Ass_R(N_k)= S$

Answer (score 1):

I have just realised how to prove this statement. It will be great if someone can verify.

Let $N$ be a maximal element in the collection of submodules $M'$ such that $Ass_R(M') \subseteq S$ due to Zorn's lemma.

I claim that $Ass_R(N) =M$. If it was not true then exists $m \in M$ such that $Rm \cong R/P$ where $P$ is a prime ideal, thus $N \subset N+Rm$.For any $n \in N$, $Rn \cong R/I$ meaning that $rn=0$ iff $r \in I$.

Concluding that $r(n+m)=0$ when $r \in I\cdot P$. So from this statement we can see that $R(n+m) \cong R/I'$. We see that $I'$ is not a prime ideal. So $Ass_R(N+Rm) \subseteq S$ and $N $ is a submodule of $N+Rm$ which contradicts our assumption $m \notin N$, so $Ass_R(N)=S$.